# Select first row that meets certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date         RunningTotal
01-05-2015   100
02-05-2015   150
03_05-2015   140
04-05-2015   130
05_05_2015   140
06-05-2015   170
07-05-2015   180
```

I need to determine the start and end of the maximum [drawdown](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/drawdown.asp) for the running total. So far I am able to determine the starting index position for the maximum drawdown and the index position of the maximum drawdown as follows:

```
df.set_index(['RunningTotal'], inplace=True)
max_drawdown_ix = np.argmax(np.maximum.accumulate(df.index) - df.index)+1
start_drawdown_ix = np.argmax(df.index[:max_drawdown_ix])
```

What I have been unable to do is determine the index position of when the drawdown ends (ie: when is the running total higher than what it was when the drawdown started). In the above example the following would be the result:

```
max_drawdown_ix occurs on 04_05_2015 which is index position 3
start_drawdown_ix occurs on 02_05_2015 which is index position 1
end_drawdown_ix occurs on 06_05_2015 which is index position 5
```

Any suggestions on how to determine when the biggest/max drawdown ends? (ie: how to determine when the first occurance is that runningtotal is more than start_drawdown_ix, which occurs after the max_drawdown_ix)

Comment: Data could contain more than one drawdown? If yes, do you need all of them of just the biggest one?

Comment: I just need the biggest one. The code I posted correctly identifies the start of the biggest drawdown, as well as the biggest drawdown position. What I need to know is when the biggest drawdown ends. (ie: when does running total become bigger than it was before the drawdown started.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's calculate your drawdown.

```
df['drawdown'] = df.RunningTotal.cummax() - df.RunningTotal
```

Next, figure out where the max drawdown occurred.

```
max_dd_idx = df.drawdown.idxmax()
max_dd_date = df.Date.iat[max_dd_idx]
>>> max_dd_date
'04-05-2015'
```

We then need to search for the first zero value before this index location to find the start of the drawdown period.

```
dd_start_idx = (df.drawdown.loc[:max_dd_idx]
                [df.drawdown.loc[:max_dd_idx] == 0].index[-1])
dd_start_date = df.Date.iat[dd_start_idx]
>>> dd_start_idx
'02-05-2015'
```

Then get the index location for the end of the max drawdown period (i.e. where the max DD first becomes zero after the Max DD).

```
dd_end_idx = (df.drawdown.loc[max_dd_idx:]
              [df.drawdown.loc[max_dd_idx:] == 0].index[0])
dd_end_date = df.Date.iat[dd_end_idx]
>>> dd_end_date
'06-05-2015'
```

Note that you will need to do bounds checkings to avoid an index error if the current drawdown period is ongoing.

```
if len(df.drawdown.loc[max_dd_idx:][df.drawdown.loc[max_dd_idx:] == 0]) == 0:
    pass  # Current drawdown period is ongoing.
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought selecting this as the correct answer was all that was required. No problem,...upvoted :)